# How does ANN deal with outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, outliers

SVM is good with outliers as it will only use the most relevant points (support vectors) to find a linear separation.

How does ANN deals with outliers?

Comment: The premise is flawed. SVMs are not robust to outliers.

Comment: This is way too general.  What ann?  (There are literally an infinite number of them.)  Which training algo?  (there are a few dozen decent ones)  Which measure of goodness?  (there are a few dozen popular ones)  Which data?  (the nature of the data and outliers has its own influence on handling)

Comment: I mean feed forward MLP.

Comment: @ Firebug - Can you explain what you mean.  As OP points out, SVM only uses the data 'closest' to the separating hyperplane, which would seem to make it robust to outliers.

Comment: If the classes are linearly separable in some feature space, then the SVM is also good with outliers.

Comment: @aginensky For what reason exactly? Even though the $\ell_2$ regularization guards against huge coefficients, and the hinge loss maximizes margins without severely penalizing outliers (it's linear after all), the fact is outliers can have *much* sway over the margin (kernel or not, the equations are the same). That's the reason robust SVMs were invented in the first place. Read [Value-at-Risk Support Vector Machine: Stability to Outliers](http://www.ise.ufl.edu/uryasev/files/2013/05/VaR-SVM.pdf).

Comment: Support Vector Machines (and classifiers) take their names from the fact that they are constructed only from the data that lies exactly on the boundary.  That is they depend only on the data points supported on the boundary.  If one takes a data point not on the boundary and perturb it slightly, it does not change the resulting hyperplane.  In particular a data point can be moved as far away from the boundary as one wants without effecting the answer.  I don't have a mathematical definintion of 'robust to outliers', but to me that would mean that SVM's are robust to outliers.

Comment: In fact, the kernel trick which is at the heart of support vector machines is based on this.  I don't have a good published reference for this, but Ch. 12 of 'Elements of Statistical Learning' has some discussion of this.

Comment: @aginensky you are thinking of outliers at the same side of the marging as their class. There are also outiliers that cross class, or in other words cross the marging. SVMs are highly sensitive to these.

Comment: Indeed I am.  My definition of outlier would informally be data that very much differs from most of the other data points.  I suppose I would also cover that under the use of the word robust as opposed to perfect.